# hyperbola curve and its arc

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to make the following diagram:
[image]

How could I make it? I find it difficult create the hyperbola's arc.

Comment: What do you know about the “bow”? Is it a simple arc (fixed radius) or can it approximated by one? Is it sine? You can also plot it directly with TikZ.

Comment: I don't know anything about the "bow". Ι just want to make only this relation between the points A and B. What I only know is that AM=MB.

Comment: Off-topic: An [MWE/code effort](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) earn's rep while you learn

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although your picture suggests otherwise, I will assume that the “bow” is in fact an arc of constant radius.

Ignoring the `dot` and `dot*` style for a minute (they both place a dot and a label at the coordinate we define later while the latter also draws the dashed lines to the axes), an arc of a constant radius can be drawn very simple using basic geometry, the `calc` library and the `intersection of` syntax (that is a wrapper for the `intersection cs`) to find the center of the radius.

I hope the comments in the code are helpful enough.

I have also added a Bézier curve (?) with the control point `C'` which is found in the same matter as `C` (the center of the arc) but lies on the tangent *DA*.

The coordinate `M` is found early on with `($(A)!.5!(B)$)`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
  every label/.append style={inner sep=+.1667em},
  dot/.style={
    label={[
        label distance=+0pt,
        shape=circle,
        fill=black,
        inner sep=+0pt,
        outer sep=+0pt,
        minimum size=+2pt,
        label={#1}
      ]center:}},
  dot*/.style={
    dot={#1},
    append after command={
      \pgfextra
        \pgfinterruptpath
          \let\myTikzlastnode\tikzlastnode
          \draw[thin,dashed] (0,0 |- \myTikzlastnode) node[left] {$P_{\myTikzlastnode}$} -| (0,0 -| \myTikzlastnode) node[below] {$Q_{\myTikzlastnode}$};
        \endpgfinterruptpath
      \endpgfextra
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\draw[<->] (0,6) node[left]  {$P$} |- node[below left] {$O$}
           (6,0) node[below] {$Q$};

\path (1,3)   coordinate[dot*=below left:$A$]       (A)
    ++(120:1) coordinate[dot =$D$] (D)
      (4,1)   coordinate[dot*=below left:$B$] (B);
;

\draw let
        % let's save D, A and B in other macros so that we can acess their x and y value separately
        \p1=(D),
        \p2=(A),
        \p3=(B),
        % then the middle between A and B is
        \p{M}=($(\p2)!.5!(\p3)$),
        % while the angles from D to A is
        \n{1-2}={atan2(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)},
        % a line orthogonal to the line between A and B has the angle of
        \n{ortho 2-3}={90+atan2(\x3-\x2,\y3-\y2)},
        % which means that the center of a circle through A and B that has the tangent DA lies at the intersection of
        \p{C}=(intersection of A--[shift=(90+\n{1-2}:10)]A and \p{M}--[shift={(\n{ortho 2-3}:10)}]\p{M}),
        % the radius is then simply (we can use either A or B to calculate the radius
        \n{radius}={veclen(\x{C}-\x3,\y{C}-\y3)},
        % the end angle at B is then also
        \n{end angle}={atan2(\x3-\x{C},\y3-\y{C})},
        %!
        %! for the Bézier curve:
        \p{C'}=(intersection of A--[shift=(\n{1-2}:10)]A and \p{M}--[shift={(\n{ortho 2-3}+180:10)}]\p{M})
      in % great, let's draw it, first the tangent
       (D) -- (A)
       % then the arc
       arc[radius=\n{radius}, start angle=\n{1-2}-90, end angle=\n{end angle}]
       % let's append another tangent at the end of the arc
       -- ++(\n{end angle}+90:1)
       % and while we're at we can also save the center of the arc in a coordiante M
%       (\p{C}) coordinate[dot=above:$C$] (C)               %?
       (\p{M}) coordinate[dot*=above right:$M$] (M)
       % let's draw the connection from A to B
       (A)--(B)
       %!
       %! for the Bézier curve
%       (\p{C'}) coordinate[dot=left:$C'$] (C') % for later %?
      ;
%\draw[thin,dotted] (A) -- (C) -- (B) -- (C') -- cycle;     %?
%\draw[thin,blue]   (A) .. controls (C') .. (B);            %?
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[This image is the same as above but shows the center of the radius `C`, the Bézier curve as well as its control point `C'`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWaqD.png) and has been compiled with the lines marked with `%?` not commented out.

Comment: @Qrrbebirlbel Firstly, thank you very much. Secondly, I don't know whether your diagram is similar to mine. My diagram has a linear part which connects the points A and B and in the half of this line there is the M point (this is why AM=MB).

Comment: @giannis I have updated my answer with the “plain” version of your image (the arc is still not a hyperbola though). The other image shows the previous version with `M` lying in the middle of `A` and `B`.

Comment: I was trying to recompile my tex and now it shows ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/ label distance', to whic
h you passed '+0pt', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 Is there any chance to clash with any other package?

Comment: @giannis Append a `%` to the sixth line: i.e. `label={[%`

Comment: still not the same result as yours, unfortunately.

Comment: @giannis Ah, yes, I see. That is because when PGF v3 came out, the syntax of `atan2` was changed, see [Q244569](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/244569).

Comment: which one should I change. I'm afraid I can't understand it from the Q244569.

Comment: @giannis You need to swap the arguments of *every* `atan2` in the code.