# Bounding lines around tax nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw lines around a number of nodes. I very much like the definition of `\convexpath` definition given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82413/drawing-a-node-surrounding-arbitrarily-places-nodes/244565#244565), but it is not working well on my setup (MacTex 2014 with all available updates).

I tried to compile [Claudio Fiandrino's first solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82423/4778), but what I get is the following, which is clearly not what I should be getting. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you try swapping the arguments to the PGFmath `atan2` function? `atan2(\x1,\y1)` becomes `atan2(\y1, \x1)` and so on.

Comment: Wow, that did it. Thanks very much for this. If you enter it as an answer, I'll vote for it and mark this closed.

Comment: What are `tax nodes`? Something to do with the IRS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When TikZ/PGF updated to version 3.0.0, the parameters of the PGFmath function [`atan2`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) where swapped. Up to version 2.10 it was

```
atan2(x, y)
```

It now is

```
atan2(y, x)
```

Think what you may of this change, however, it breaks backward compatibility, as you need to swap arguments in the linked code as well.

---

For my own libraries and purposes I created two substitute functions `atanXY` and `atanYX`

```
\csname pgfmathatan2@\endcsname{0}{1}
\ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=0pt % atan2(y, x)
  \pgfmathdeclarefunction{atanXY}{2}{\csname pgfmathatan2@\endcsname{#2}{#1}}
  \pgfmathdeclarefunction{atanYX}{2}{\csname pgfmathatan2@\endcsname{#1}{#2}}
\else                       % atan2(x, y)
  \pgfmathdeclarefunction{atanXY}{2}{\csname pgfmathatan2@\endcsname{#1}{#2}}
  \pgfmathdeclarefunction{atanYX}{2}{\csname pgfmathatan2@\endcsname{#2}{#1}}
\fi
```

which was even more important when switching between the 2.10 and the CVS version.

Nowadays

```
  \pgfmathdeclarefunction{atanXY}{2}{\pgfmathatantwo@{#2}{#1}}
  \pgfmathdeclarefunction{atanYX}{2}{\pgfmathatantwo@{#1}{#2}}
```

should be enough.

This also allows it again to use `atanXY(\p{<name>})` after one has used calc’s

```
let \p{<name>}=(<coordinates>) … in
```

path operator.
The `\p{<name>}` macro just expands to `\x{<name>},\y{<name>}` which is usually used inside TikZ coordinate specifications.